# Where should my Python 3 modules be?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, osx-snow-leopard

I recently installed Python 3 on my Mac OSX 10.6.8 and I haven't had any problems with modules or imports until now. I'm writing a function that tests whether or not a triangle is right angled based on the length of the sides and the guide that the exercise was in has a bunch of equalities to test so I can see if it works:

```
testEqual(is_rightangled(1.5,2.0,2.5), True)
testEqual(is_rightangled(4.0,8.0,16.0), False)
testEqual(is_rightangled(4.1,8.2,9.1678787077), True)
testEqual(is_rightangled(4.1,8.2,9.16787), True)
testEqual(is_rightangled(4.1,8.2,9.168), False)
testEqual(is_rightangled(0.5,0.4,0.64031), True)
```

I should apparently import a function called testEqual(a,b,c) from a module called test, since the example programme in the guide starts with `from test import testEqual`, but when I typed that into my file I got this message:

```
  from test import testEqual
ImportError: cannot import name testEqual
```

I suppose I should specify the path to the test module, but I can't find it my Python 3 library anywhere in my computer – just the 2.x ones that came installed with the computer, which are in `/Library/Python`. `import turtle` and `import math` worked, so it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`test` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) in the Python stdlib doesn't contain a function called `testEqual()`. Its documentation starts with

> **Note:** The `test` package is meant for internal use by Python only. It is
>   documented for the benefit of the core developers of Python. Any use
>   of this package outside of Python’s standard library is discouraged as
>   code mentioned here can change or be removed without notice between
>   releases of Python.

Are you sure that this guide you're following doesn't have its own `test.py` program that you're supposed to use instead?

Comment: The guide has something called activecode which basically lets you write Python programmes and run them on your browser, so it would make sense if it did have one installed. There's no link to download it though, so I might try to write my own `testEqual()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write your testEqual() function make note of the directory you are working in. For instance on my mac I created a directory (folder) in documents so my path looks like: /Users/myName/Documents/python.  Save your function (module) as testEqual.py and when you write you test.py script import testEqual after the shebang line.  Once you have your scripts debugged your modules will be in a folder that python creates titled **pycache** don't remove that as it is compiled code.  Now, as long as you are working in the same dir as your module you should not need to do anything other than use the import statement.